# PHP Curl getting 502: Bad Gateway Error

Tags: php, curl

From the browser the url is working. When I am trying with PHP curl - I am getting

```
502 - Bad Gateway error
```

Here is my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $query_string);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

And the error -

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.4</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try to do that from the console using `curl` ?

Comment: I am trying from the console and getting that error...

Comment: The error isn't from the curl script. I suspect malformed request uri. Can you `var_dump($url . $query_string)` - what's the output??

Comment: Thanks Latheesan Kanes...I had to urlencode the query string...the uri was malformed.