# PHP curl taking so long to execute and in the end it does not do anything on de nodejs server

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I'm setting up a new notification server with nodejs and socket.io. The server it is working, with postman I can send a POST request and indeed sends the notification but with PHP it's taking for ages to send the POST with curl and it's not really working

The nodejs server is running on debian 9, I got a SSL certificate from let's encrypt so it's authenticated, like I said before with postman ( https://www.getpostman.com/ ) I can make the POST request and works. I'm sending headers with a secret key and body with data to the notification

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 49152;
const notificationSecret = process.env.NOTIFICATION_SECRET; 
var server;

if(process.env.SSL_KEY && process.env.SSL_CERT) {
    var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY_PATH),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH)
    };
    server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
} else {
    console.log("Error creating the server, missing KEY OR CERT");
}


const io = require('socket.io')(server);


server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server listening at port %d', port));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
```

... more but not important

and PHP

```
$data = array("notification" => "IF THIS WORKS", "channel" => "myChannel"); 

$payload = json_encode($data);

// Prepare new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init('IP/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

// Set HTTP Header for POST request 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'notification_secret: ')
);

// Submit the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL session handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Anyone has any idea what can I try to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up cURL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467449/how-to-speed-up-curl-in-php)

Comment: The problem it's not how fast is not doing anything, it's that stays there for ever and in the end does not send the data to the nodejs server

Comment: Is your IP blocked?

Comment: No.. like I said it's working with Postman, really fast almost instantly

Comment: did you check the output of curl error? after curl_exec($ch); -> echo curl_error($ch); ?

Comment: Getting timeout error, 30 sec
and 502 error

Comment: Maybe similar error like: [PHP Curl getting 502: Bad Gateway Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424902/php-curl-getting-502-bad-gateway-error)

Comment: Thank you but not
Well I fixed it doing instead of curl, I did an ajax POST request and it worked, thank you anyway guys